# How to show pre-selected colors unsing holoviews image

Tags: image, colors, grid, holoviews

I'd like to use holoviews image to visualize colors from a list of hex values.
Using hv.Image from [here](https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Gridded_Datasets.html):

`hv.Image((range(10), range(5), np.random.rand(5, 10)), datatype=['grid'])`

how can I assign a list of hex color values (esp. a pandas column of hex values) to the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how to define a colormap, it's like this (though usually with a lot more colors):

```
import holoviews as hv, numpy as np
hv.extension("bokeh")

colors = ["Red", "#00FF00", "#AA2211"]
hv.Image((range(10), range(5), np.random.rand(5, 10)), datatype=['grid']).opts(cmap=colors)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For those who wonder how to get the pandas column into the cmap: `list(df.loc[:,'color'])` could do the trick (with 'color' as the dataframe column with hex values).